# Expand `*` inside of variable value in bash

Tags: bash

Can I create a bash variable with `*` in the value and then have that `*` expanded by the shell upon use?

E.g.

```
sourcefiles=/path/*.phtml*
filesfound=0

for f in $sourcefiles;
do
  echo "Found file named: $f";
  mv $f /other/path/"$f"
  (($filesfound++))
done
```

This is running as part of a cron job, and I am getting an error in my email saying:

```
mv: cannot stat `/path/*.phtml*': No such file or directory
```

So it seems to me that the `*` is not expanding, perhaps only when it doesn't find any matches...

Comment: Why do you think that isn't what your code already does?

Comment: Oops, very good point. Just a second and let me add that key part of my question.

Comment: BTW, all-caps variable names are reserved for variables provided or used by shell and system utilities -- you should use lower- or mixed-case names for your own variables. See relevant specification in fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a namespace.

Comment: ...now, you've got other bugs -- should be `mv "$f" /other/path/"$f"`, f'rinstance, and what you're asking for is certainly not good practice (you can't do globbing without also getting string-splitting without playing with some `set` options or clearing `IFS`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, I will change them all to lower case.

Comment: ...which is why it's actually preferred to store the values in a variable rather than storing the pattern: `sourcefiles=( /path/*.phtml* )` creates an array called `sourcefiles` which can be expanded to all matching files with `"${sourcefiles[@]}"`. Caveat: If *no* files match, the array will contain the pattern itself, unless the `nullglob` option is enabled.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've learned more about shell scripting in the last 15 seconds than I did last year, I think. But yes, the problem is that many times no files will match.

Comment: BTW, if you *are* doing the store-in-an-array trick, you can count the items in that array with `"${#sourcefiles[@]}"`, or check if the first one exists (adequate to know if the glob matched anything) with `[[ -e $sourcefiles ]]`.

Comment: BTW, you don't need a `$` operator inside of a math context; just `(( ++varname ))` will do. (To understand why that's preferable to `(( varname++ ))`, see some of the examples in BashFAQ #105: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: @nortally, "dereference" in bash usually refers to indirect references -- a very different operation with a very different syntax (and also, as of bash 4.3, available through adoption of ksh's namevars).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Actually I think I didn't have the `$` operator in my code but typed it here out of habit. Bash is more quirky than organic chemistry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct: Not expanding is default behavior when there are no matches!

This lets

```
ls *.txt
```

return an error akin to

```
ls: no file '*.txt' found
```

instead of falling back to its default behavior of listing all files (as it would if given no arguments).

---

If you *want* to evaluate to an empty list, use:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

...or just check if any results exist:

```
for f in $sourcefiles; do
  [[ -e $f ]] || continue
  echo "Found file named: $f";
  mv "$f" /other/path/"$f"
  ((++filesfound))
done
```

Alternately, consider:

```
shopt -s nullglob
sourcefiles=( /path/*.phtml* )
filesfound=${#sourcefiles[@]}

# print entire list, with names quoted to make hidden characters &c readable
printf 'Found file named: %q\n' "${sourcefiles[@]}"

# warning: this only works if the list is short enough to fit on one command line
mv -- "${sourcefiles[@]}" /other/path/
```

Comment: So then perhaps I don't really have a problem, just no matches. But then I am getting a false positive in my "filesfound" variable.

Comment: Short-circuiting the loop when returned an item that doesn't exist will solve that.

Comment: ...see the `|| continue` in my example.

Comment: I'll test this right now and likely get back to you with a check mark and an upvote. I'll also try it with `sourcefiles=(/path/*.phtml*)`

Comment: *nod*. You'll want to combine the array usage with either a `[[ -e $sourcefiles ]]` test or precede it with a `shopt -s nullglob`, and be sure to use the `for f in "${sourcefiles[@]}"` syntax on expansion.

Comment: BTW, if this is potentially a large number of files and you have GNU mv, consider something like `(( ${#sourcefiles[@]} )) && printf '%s\0' "${sourcefiles[@]}" | xargs -0 mv -t /other/path --`, which will reuse a single invocation of `mv` for as many files as it can fit on the command line, rather than running one `mv` per file. (the `-t` is a GNU extension, hence the compatibility caveat).

Comment: ...btw, if you're interested in more details on shell arrays, see BashFAQ #5: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005

Comment: I see, so I would use `sourcefiles=/path/*.phtml*` with `for f in $sourcefiles;`, and `sourcefiles=( /path/*.phtml* )` with `for f in "${sourcefiles[@]}"`.  I instinctively feel like the second option is better, programming-wise, but I can't explain it.

Comment: If you want a concrete reason the second path is better, look at what happens if your directory name has a space in it -- you can quote/escape the name when it's hardcoded bash syntax, but you can't do that in an expansion -- see BashFAQ #50 -- and thus need to clear IFS to prevent string-splitting, which is a side-effecting operation.